# Ordenação de lista encadeada BubbleSort c

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, bubblesort

Lista.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct lista  Lista;

struct lista
{
       int valor; 
       struct lista * proximo; 
       };

//Operação Criacao 

Lista * cria_lista(void)
{
 return (NULL);      
}

//Operação SET - setar valor da Lista
Lista * set_lista(Lista * l, int a)
{
 Lista * novo = (Lista *) malloc (sizeof(Lista));
 novo->valor = a; 
 novo->proximo = l;
 return(novo);
}


//Mosta Lista
void view_lista(Lista * l)
{
Lista * pl;
      for (pl = l; pl != NULL; pl = pl->proximo)
      {
          printf("Valor %d  Endereco %x Proximo endereco: %x \n", pl->valor, pl,pl->proximo);
      }
}
void view_lista2(Lista * l)
{
Lista * pl;
      for (pl = l; pl != NULL; pl = pl->proximo)
      {
          printf("Valor %d  Endereco %x Proximo endereco: %x valor: %d\n", pl->valor, pl,pl->proximo, pl->proximo->valor);
          
      }
}

void ordena_lista(Lista * l)
{
Lista * atual;
Lista * anterior= NULL;
lista * aux; 
int tamanho_lista = 0;


      //Verifica o tamanho da lista
      for (atual = l; atual != NULL; atual = atual->proximo)
      {
          tamanho_lista++;
      }
      
      printf("\nTamanho %d \n", tamanho_lista);

      for (int i = 0; i< tamanho_lista; i++)
        {
            for (atual = l; atual->proximo != NULL; atual = atual->proximo)
            {
                
                if(atual->valor > atual->proximo->valor)
                {           
                    
                    aux = atual->proximo;
                    anterior->proximo = atual->proximo;
                    atual->proximo = atual->proximo->proximo;
                    aux->proximo = atual;
                    //printf("atual:%d  proximo:%d  anterior:%x \n", atual->valor, atual->proximo->valor, anterior);
                    //printf("atual:%x  proximo:%x  anterior:%x \n", atual, atual->proximo, anterior);
                    atual->valor;
                    atual->proximo->valor;
                    atual->proximo->proximo->valor;
                    anterior->valor;
                    aux->valor;
                    //view_lista2(l);
                      if (atual->proximo == NULL)
                      {
                        break;
                        }
            }
            //printf("atual:%d  proximo:%d  anterior:%x \n", atual->valor, atual->proximo->valor, anterior);
            printf("quebra aqui \n");
            anterior = atual;
            }
      }
}
```

lista.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lista.h"


main()
{
printf("inicio do Programa\n");

Lista * lis = cria_lista();


lis = set_lista(lis,13);
lis = set_lista(lis,20);
lis = set_lista(lis,21);
lis = set_lista(lis,14);


view_lista(lis);

ordena_lista(lis); 
printf("corta aqui\n");

view_lista(lis);

system("pause");
     
      
}
```

Comment: E ... como diria Carlos Tevez ¿ la pregunta ? Qual sua dúvida ou questão ?

Comment: Não duplique perguntas. Os comentários aqui foram bloqueados para que continue na [pergunta original](/q/589160/3635).